# AsyncTask Android Fetch New Data

Tags: android

I have create `PreferenceFragment class` that reads mypreferences from an `xml file`
Basically list of Links

In `MainActivity class` I have create private `class AsyncTask` that I use to fetch data from website.

`MainActivity onCreate` method Iam calling `execute()` method:

```
new asynObj().execute();
```

And for `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` method I call method inside `MainActivity`:

```
onSharedPreferenceChanged(){
 // I call method to fetch new Data
  refetchData()
}
```

`refetchData()` method I use it to grab new data from different website, but the problem is that UI does not change again.

```
public void reloadData() {
    new asynObj().execute();
}
```

My problem is that I want each time `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` changes I will call `reloadData()` and fetch new data and use it to update the UI.

My code works fine except for re fetching new data each time

Comment: What was the problem? Any error occurred? If yes add the log here.

Comment: if the code is working fine till u receive callback in onSharedPreferenceChanged() then please post the code where you are facing issue or any error or check if the list is populated or refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying your data in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, make sure you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in your adapter.